# Are there Django short tags for web development? If there are, how to enable it?

Tags: php, python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

Example of native PHP code:

```
<h1><?php echo "Hello world!"; ?></h1>
```

Example of PHP short tags:

```
<h1><? echo "Hello world!"; ?></h1>
```

Are there Python code that looks like this:

```
<h1><% print "Hello world!"; %></h1>
```

If there are, how to enable that?

Comment: This is very much a Django question - python, unlike PHP, is not specifically tailored to making websites

Comment: @Eric So Django have a template engine.. But pointing the title of this question to Django is unfair for other web framework that also have a template engine.. Anyway, do you know some other programming languages that their tags works a little bit the same to PHP *(other than ASP.NET)*?

Comment: @Servant what is the specific problem you are trying to solve with a language that works like PHP but is not PHP? In other words, if you want PHP functionality, why not use PHP in the first place?

Comment: @miraculixx I mean a language for web development that can be declared by a tag, just like PHP.. Do you know some?

Answer (score 2):

Generally Python works a little bit different to PHP. You need a template engine to do that. See: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating

Comment: Do you know some other programming languages that their tags works a little bit same to PHP, other than ASP.NET?

Comment: @Servant is there a special reason for that? I can assure you python is great for web development

Comment: @Alvaro Yes, because I'm still seriously looking for the language which have tags that works a little bit the same to PHP..

Answer (score 1):

A big yes. The tags in Django look like this:

```
<p>{{ this_is_a_variable }}</p>
{% for letter in 'This is a statement' %}
    <p>{{ letter }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Django is a very good framework, unlike anything I have ever seen (part of it is because Python is a great language!)

You can't execute arbitrary code here, but take it as an advantage: you will respect MVC better